# New Project Android Studio 2.3.1 Problems

Tags: android, android-studio, new-project

I just updated `Android Studio` at the version `2.3.1` and I want to start a new project. But the `Menu` changed and I can't find the right way to create an empty project with all standard libraries..
[image of new project with updated version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNzet.png)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-Launch Android Studio.

2-In the Welcome to Android Studio screen, choose New Project.

3-In the New Project window, enter the application name, module name, package name, and project location.

if Couldn't understand see link for more information.

[Link](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/training/build-first-android-app/get-started-studio/index.html)

Comment: I know how to start a new project.. but if you see the image i posted on my question. the window which opens it's different than normal window of the new project.. watch the image, please

Comment: i saw image . @P.Halley

Comment: open another Project with **Open With** in windows and then in menu open new Project.

Comment: try reinstall android-studio @P.Halley

Comment: I reinstalled and that's not working again.. I don't know what to do!!

Comment: i update my android-studio to 2.3.1 but every things is normal ! @P.Halley

Answer (score 0):

I was also seeing the similar issue. This happened because android support plugin was disabled. After enabling Android Support, I was able to create normal Android Project.

You can enable it by going to File->Settings->Plugins and Enable the Android Support plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have face problem with newest version 2.3.1 Android Studio.it generated wrong debug APK its some time generate lesser size of APK file which is crash at launch time.